# Accessing a Web API service enabled with windows authentication from an angular4 application in google chrome

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have a Web API service created with Windows authentication . I have an Angular 4 application which needs to invoke the Web API service. Everything works fine if I use internet explorer but it does not work if I browse the angular application using Google Chrome but I need to use Google Chrome as many HTML 5 features are not supported in internet explorer.

It would be a great help if you can please provide a solution of invoking Web API service with Windows Authentication from Angular 4 application using Google Chrome.

Comment: what does "does not work using Google Chrome" mean, exactly?  are you getting errors in the console?  unexpected results? please explain what is actually happening, because there is no reason that a Web API would care what browser you are using.....

Comment: When we run the Angular4 application using Google Chrome and the Web API service is invoked by the application, in console, we get XMLHttpRequest cannot load <web api url>. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value '<angular application url>' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin '<angular application url>' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Look up CORS.  This is a pretty standard error, with a very common solution.